# How to send image for facial recognition to python based cloud program from android app (Java based) and then get the result back from python to java?

Tags: java, python, android, computer-vision, face-recognition

I upload images from java based android app to firebase storage and store their links in the firebase real-time database. I want to send links to the images to the python program which is hosted on the cloud and apply face recognition on those images. After the face recognition, the python must send a response back to the android app or update my real-time database so that I can get results in the android application.
Thank you

Comment: what Python program? Usually people use Python to create web page which has special url to get infomation from Application - like `/get_link/<your_link>` - and this gives back `unique number` which later Application can use with other link to check if result is ready - `/get_result/<unique-number>`. And then Application has to periodically check this url to see if there is result and get it.

Comment: other method is to add access to firebase in Python program - and it should periodically check if there is new information. And if there is new link, then get data, process it and put result in the same place. And then Application has periodically check if there is result in firebase. It also may need `unique number` to somehow check correct result.

Comment: @furas I do not know where exactly should I put my python program, I am currently running it on colab, but wherever necessary I can move it. And I think the later method would be the best if it checks firebase and process my data and then put the result back. Could you please help me with the firebase method, just guide me where should I start from and I will go for it. Thank you

Comment: I never used `firebase` but I would start at official documentation for `firebase` - maybe they have Python module and examples how to use it. I found [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python)

Comment: I found also [Python Client for Google Cloud Firestore](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/index.html) which looks interesting.

Comment: @furas I would say that I am directed to a right path thank you for that. Could you please help me where should I put my python program? The python program should execute when firebase is updated, it does not have any interface it is just for processing the data and keeping that back in firebase.

Comment: it should run all time - so it should run in some loop (like `while True`) and check if there is new data in firebase, process data, and send result back. If there is no new data then it could sleep few seconds (to use less CPU). It would need some server which runs all time - `colab` will stop when you exit. And with access to google servers - I don't know if [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) gives access to Google but it block access to the most portals to stop sending spam from server. You would have to check some servers in your country.